# Killing user session using http DELETE

Tags: javascript, html, json, http, rest

I am working on a website which is connected to a rest-api. Users can log into the webpage. I have a logout button, behind which I need to write the javascript/json/http request to kill the user session. This is what I have, can anyone tell me if it makes any sense?

```
<form action="http://apiaddresshere.com" method="delete" id = "myform">
          <input type = "submit" value="Logout">
        </form>

<script>


var form = document.getElementById("myform");

form.onsubmit = function (e) {
  // stop the regular form submission
  e.preventDefault();


  // construct an HTTP request
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open(form.method, form.action, true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');

  // send the null data as JSON
  xhr.send(JSON.stringify());

  xhr.onloadend = function () {
    // done
  };
};


</script>
```

Comment: Whats the problem your having? "Does it make sense" doesn't really make much sense...

Comment: Hi Lee, Im in the process of learning how to use these technologies and just looking for a little guidance as to whether or not I am going in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just POST to `http://apiaddresshere.com/logout`.  That would be a lot simpler & more standard than trying to pull off some corner-case use of the HTTP api.

Simple & standard works & keeps working, I recommend going that way :)

God only knows what proxy servers or corporate firewalls are going to make of your DELETE request. But hey, when they don't like it, the app won't work.. and you'll rightly get blamed.

Comment: Hmmm I didn't realise I could do that. Can you give me an idea of what that might look like? Total newbie to web dev and rest so finding it a bit confusing.

Comment: Maybe the rest of the buttons are AJAX, but logout will normally always take the user to a different page! So just do a plain vanilla form submit, and have the server redirect to the `/login` page. Nothing AJAX'y in this one, at all.

Comment: If I do that, does it mean I don't need the javascript at all?

Comment: Correct, this doesn't need JS, just plain HTML.

Answer (score 1):

```
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="logout()">Logout</a>
    function logout(){
    $.ajax({
      url: "logout.php",
    type:"post",
dataType: 'json'
    }).done(function() {

    });
    }
```

Comment: It simple idea , you post the json null data to session killer page , ıt returns to you json.

Comment: Ok, so where is "logout.php" coming from?

Comment: I wrote it you can change it.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid `logout` and `login` URIs. There are verbs, not nouns. URIs should represent resources, not actions.

If you have to have a session use a URI like

```
apiaddresshere.com/sessions/23245252354323
```

or something like that. Then to "logout" the user sends a `DELETE` request to that session resource.

Of course sessions aren't particularly RESTful in the first place, so this might be a moot point.